# how does the image signal processor run

Tags: linux-kernel, camera, imageprocessor

I know the cpu load code from memory and execute the code. The address of kernel code is above 0xc0000000 in 32 bit linux os. But I don’t know how the isp(image signal processor) run. Does isp also load code from memory above 0xc0000000 and execute the code? How does cpu communicate with isp ?  The isp handle the raw image with arithmetic code. how does it load the arithmetic?

Comment: "*The address of kernel code is above 0xc0000000 ...*" -- That's a *virtual* address. The Linux kernel is typically loaded in low *physical* memory. "*Does isp also load code from memory above 0xc0000000 ...?*" -- You really need to study the datasheet and board schematics for the specific ISP (& board) you're using. Typically the ISP (i.e. a coprocessor) would not be sharing an MMU with the CPU, so such an ISP would be unaware of such virtual addresses. If you're actually referring to an IS interface integrated in an SoC, then such a peripheral has embedded/hardcoded algorithms.